# Symantec Ghost Error Trying to Image Win/Linux

Tags: linux, imaging, ghost

I'm having a problem trying to use Ghost on one of my labs. This semester one of our instructors wanted to have a lab that can dual boot Win Xp and Linux. I set it up and pulled an image with ghost with no problems, but pushing the image back out causes Ghost to crash with the following error.

ABORT: 8027 GeneralException

Inside the error log file I find:

[327782] No free space big enough to create volume.

The computers I am imaging are all identical so there shouldn't be a problem with drive space.

the partition layout is:
[  Win XP Primary ]{ Extended [ Win Logical Drive ][ Win Logical Drive ]} [Linux LVM Group]

If anyone has any ideas I would appreciate it. Will be a late night tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Symantec Ghost Solution Suite 2.5 doesn't provide good support for LVM volumes, but I'm not sure if that's the version that you're using or if there are other versions that support LVM without problems (you can take a look at [this article](http://service1.symantec.com/SUPPORT/on-technology.nsf/ppfdocs/2008071416033360?Open&dtype=corp&src=&seg=&om=1&om_out=prod)).

If you have no choice about using LVM (for example, because it was required by the instructor), I'd suggest using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) instead of Ghost.

But if you can avoid LVM, you could use ext3 partitions for Linux and clone with Ghost.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem a few times with both Ghost and Drive Image. What worked for me was to resize one of the partitions so that there is some unallocated space left over on the drive and then take the image. I've found that the ammount of the unallocated space required depends on the drive geometry but genarelly a hundred meg or so is sufficient.